# Alert handling in Selenium WebDriver (selenium 2) with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, alert

I want to detect whether an alert is popped up or not. Currently I am using the following code:

```
    try {
        Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();

        // check if alert exists
        // TODO find better way
        alert.getText();

        // alert handling
        log().info("Alert detected: {}" + alert.getText());
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

The problem is that if there is no alert on the current state of the web page, it waits for a specific amount of time until the timeout is reached, then throws an exception and therefore the performance is really bad.

Is there a better way, maybe an alert event handler which I can use for dynamically occurring alerts?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is what worked for me using Explicit Wait from here [WebDriver: Advanced Usage](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

```
public void checkAlert() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting and could do the trick. Is it possible to set the timeout of the wait method to zero?

Answer (score 16):

Write the following method:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    } // try
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } // catch
}
```

Now, you can check whether alert is present or not by using the method written above as below:

```
if (isAlertPresent()) {
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.accept();
```

You can also decline the alert box:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert().dismiss();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try 
    {
        //Handle the alert pop-up using seithTO alert statement
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        //Print alert is present
        System.out.println("Alert is present");

        //get the message which is present on pop-up
        String message = alert.getText();

        //print the pop-up message
        System.out.println(message);

        alert.sendKeys("");
        //Click on OK button on pop-up
        alert.accept();
    } 
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e) 
    {
        //if alert is not present print message
        System.out.println("alert is not present");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 try{
        if(webDriver.switchTo().alert() != null){
           Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
           alert.getText();
           //etc.
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

If that doesn't work, you could try looping through all the window handles and see if the alert exists. I'm not sure if the alert opens as a new window using selenium.

```
for(String s: webDriver.getWindowHandles()){
 //see if alert exists here.
}
```

Comment: Sadly, both solutions do not work. The first is as slow as my code because it already creates the exception while having a timeout. The second does not recognize alerts.

Comment: @djangofan - don't you have annoying delays?

Comment: @Alp - caused by what exactly?  What do you refer to?

Comment: If you use that code to verify if an alert exists or not, there should be a delay if it not exists. Is that so? Because i tried to minimize that delay/timeout, but had no luck.

Comment: Also, maybe try updating the selenium jars. When I was using Selenium, they were having new releases almost once a month, sometimes twice a month.