# check whether model dialog box is present or not in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there anyway to check whether an model dialog box is present in Selenium web driver? I am using the following code:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent()
{
    try
    {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        robotClass();
        System.out.println("Model dialog is present");
        return true;
    } 
    catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Model dialog is not present");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

This code is working fine for checking whether alert dialog box is present or not. And I want to check whether model dialog box is present or not in selenium using java. Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: edit it and make it look better

Comment: sorry i am new to Stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

I believe the second answer to this question is the answer you're looking for : [How to check if an alert exists using WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467471/webdriver-how-to-check-if-an-alert-exists)

Comment: My question is no need to wait for alert and all...just i want to check whether any model dialog box is present or not while running the application..                                                               Note:My question is Model dialog box not an alert.and model dialog is different and alert box is different.