# Test if alert box is present

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium in C# and I tried to use the following code to test the presence of a confirm message box (displayed with the javascript function confirm()) and accept it:

```
IAlert alert = this.Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
if (alert != null)
{
  alert.Accept();
}
```

However, this test doesn't work and I get an exception at the first line when the message box doesn't exist

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an alert exists using WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467471/how-to-check-if-an-alert-exists-using-webdriver)

Comment: the following [C# answer covers it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879064/542251)