# using selenium with python to handle confirmation alerts when they appear

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium with python for the website automation,and that includes navigation and file downloads.If the page is idle for around 15 mins(roughly,not exact),confirmation pop up appears warning the session timeout and it asks to click "OK" to continue.
I know I can use the following code to deal with the confirmation pop up

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

But how can I click "OK"in the confirmation popup whenever it appears?Do I have hto keep checking every 30 seconds if the confirmation popup exists?

Comment: Why do you have such a long IDLE time in your test? Does this popup appear always?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone here had a similar question as you: [How to check if an alert exists using WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467471/how-to-check-if-an-alert-exists-using-webdriver)

If you run `driver.switch_to.alert` when there is no alert actually present, you will receive a `NoAlertPresentException`. So, the basic idea is to write a method with a try / catch block that attempts `driver.switch_to.alert`, and returns true or false based on the presence of an exception.

Here's an example:

```
public boolean doesAlertExist() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        driver.switch_to.alert(); 
        return true; 
    }  
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }  
}
```

As far as your timing issue goes (alert pops up every 15ish minutes or so) -- you can try to write a wrapper method for `driver.findElement()` and `element.click()` that checks for the presence of the alert implicitly. Specific details about the method will depend on the project, but here's an example of something simple:

```
public IWebElement findElementWrapped(By by)
{
    if (doesAlertExist())
    {
        driver.switch_to.alert().accept(); // accept the alert
        return driver.findElement(by); // use selenium's standard findElement
    }
    else
    {
        // no alert exists, just find the element
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }
}
```

With this code, you can check for the alert every time you try to find an element on the page, but you only have to write the line of code once. You can use this method in action like this:

```
// check for alert, accept alert if it exists, get the desired web element
IWebElement myElement = driver.findElementWrapped(by);
```