# isAlertPresent? using WebDriverBackedSelenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selenium 2 Alert handling with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/selenium-2-alert-handling-with-java)

If I use `driver.switchTo.alert();` for checking whether the alert is present or not it, it takes more than 2 seconds.

But, if I use below logic for checking, it takes less than 1 second.

```
Selenium sel=new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "");
b = sel.isAlertPresent();
```

But the problem is that if an alert is not present, it is returning false, and if the alert *is* present instead it throws an `UnhandledAlertException` instead of just returning true.

Why is it throwing this exception instead of returning true?

Comment: this topic has been already discussed here:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/selenium-2-alert-handling-with-java
Hope this helps you)

Comment: thank you polschikov. But, here my doubt is Why WebDriverBackedSelenium throwing exception if alert present? instead of throwing true. Is that issue with WebDriverBackedSelenium?