# Press ENTER key in Selenium WebDriver with java when element property not present

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with Java to automate the webpages

When I enter the url, I am getting the authentication required dialog box

I am able to enter the username and password by configuring profile
but I am not able to click on OK button

Note: Not able to get the ok button property so am not able to
use the below code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Is there any other way to press on ok button through webdriver?

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for this button?

Comment: after invoking url am getting the dialog box which contains ok button

Comment: am not able to view page scorce to get html code

Comment: is it a javascript pop up box?

Comment: yes it is java script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert handling in selenium webdriver (selenium 2) with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/alert-handling-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-with-java)

Answer (score 5):

You need to handle it as an alert box,
wait for popup to appear and click OK.

Below code waits up to a maximum of 10 seconds for the popup to be present and then accepts it by clicking OK. Although wait is optional.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Answer (score 4):

Handling credential boxes is not possible directly using Selenium You can use the JAVA AWT robot class to press enter. This class is available in the java API itself.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Alternatively, you can use AutoIt or an image based testing tool like SIKULI http://www.sikuli.org.

Please note that when you are using these solutions, the workstation screen cannot be locked while running the test cases.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code snippet:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

It will definitely work.

Comment: Could you please explain why your code helps the OP?

Comment: This was not the best answer SO has ever seen but it was just what I needed to figure out the problem I was facing.