# Dismissing a print dialog in Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

I'm using Chrome as a browser and can't quite figure out how to dismiss a print dialog that appears on click of a particular button. 
I have tried using `browser.dismissAlert();` and `browser.keys([browser.Keys.ESCAPE]);` to hit the escape button, and neither works. I'm not sure that Nightwatch is aware that there is a dialog at all.

I've been searching online and can't seem to find a solution... anyone got any ideas please?

Comment: Using Selenium you need to switch to the alert and accept it. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13714614/1555990) although not specifically for your question, does have an example of how to switch to and accept an alert.

Comment: I did try that, and it hasn't worked, unfortunately! I've seen similar questions where people haven't had this issue in other browsers, so I have a feeling it's that Chrome isn't letting the test interact with it

Comment: If .acceptAlert() worked but .dismissAlert() , you can post this issue on github, may be it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as it turns out, Selenium cannot handle Chrome dialogs. I did however find a solution by reading [this page](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and adding `--disable-print-preview` to the chromeOptions in the nightwatch.json file in my project.

This dismissed the Chrome print dialog, but still brings up the Mac system dialog, and I don't think Selenium capabilities extends to system dialogs, so for the purpose of testing, I've just disabled the print functionality.

Shame I didn't find a better solution, but just wanted to update for those of you upvoting