# Selenium Java - ChromeDriver - Getting rid of an alert

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get rif od an alert as displayed in the image:

[image]

This alert **can be easily dismmised** by pressing escape or return keys.
But I cannot get it done using selenium.

First, I am switching to the window using:

```
m_parentWindowHandler = m_chromeWebdriver.getWindowHandle();
.
.
.
m_chromeWebdriver.switchTo().window(m_parentWindowHandler);
```

Then I tried

```
    Actions action = new Actions(m_chromeWebdriver);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

(also with Keys.ESCAPE)

Comment: Have a look this. Seems to be a duplicate .---  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/alert-handling-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-with-java

Comment: The dialog comes from PDF viewer. If you don't care about this dialog, and just want to get rid of it, you could disable Chrome PDF Viewer in chrome://plugins/

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks. This would be a sufficient solution for me.