# How to Handle pop ups in selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to handle pop up that coming after submitting the data on a page, pop up like *OK* And *Cancel* . (in Java )

Please check attached image

Note: i tried Alert and this #8244723

Thanks   [pop up like attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpbIo.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert handling in Selenium WebDriver (selenium 2) with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/alert-handling-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-with-java)

Comment: thanks , but this is not solving my issue. any way to handle pop up by Robot class  or Mouse Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following one line code when that pop will arise:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```