# Unexpected modal dialog closes

Tags: selenium-webdriver

On clicking Accept Button I get a confirmation window to press OK. 
I try to press the OK button

```
pageDriver.Click("Supplier_HomePage","test_AcceptRft");
pageDriver.Click("Supplier_HomePage", "test_OK")
```

Note: I couldn't inspect the element in the modal dialog box. At the same time it's not an alert

The confirmation window closes automatically so quickly and I get an exception 
 Unexpected modal dialog (text: You are accepting the invitation on behalf of ... (312321).)

Comment: Seems like an Alert to me. [Try switching to alert first and then accepting it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714614/4193730) Click actions actually doesn't work on an alert.

Comment: It was firefox which was dismissing the alert automatically. I added capability to firefox driver apabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior,"ignore");

Comment: So, Is it working now ?

Comment: yes its working

Comment: Awesome.. you found your way out.. :)